# n-dimensional interpolation c++ algorithm

Tags: c++, interpolation, linear-interpolation

How can I implement n-dimensional interpolation in C++? In ideal case I would like to have it generic on actual kernel so that I can switch between e.g., linear and polynomial interpolation (perhaps as a start: linear interpolation). This article ( http://pimiddy.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/n-dimensional-interpolation/ ) discusses this stuff but I have two problems:
1) I could not understand how to implement the "interpolate" method shown in the article in C++
2) More importantly I want to use it in a scenario where you have "multiple independent variables (X)" and "1 dependent variable (Y)" and somehow interpolate on both (?)

For example, if n=3 (i.e. 3-dimensional) and I have the following data:

```
#X1 X2 X3 Y
10  10 10 3.45
10  10 20 4.52
10  20 15 5.75
20  10 15 5.13
```

....

How could I know value of Y (dependent variable) for a particular combination of X (independent variables): 17 17 17

I know there exists other ways such as decision trees and SVM but here I am here interested in interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at a set of interpolation alrogithms (including C++ implementation) at [alglib](http://www.alglib.net/interpolation/).

Also it should be noted that neural networks ([backpropagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) nets, for example) are treated as good interpolators.

If your question is about the specific article, it's out of my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks. My question is not about a specific article. Actually I want an algorithm that I can use in my C++ application (preferably not in the form of an external library but rather source code to embed in my application).